# setting association on both sides sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have the following models :

```
var User = Seq.define('user', {
    firstName: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          field: 'first_name' 
    },
    lastName: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
});

var Chip = Seq.define('bourse', {
     name: {
           type: Sequelize.STRING,
           field: 'first_name' 
});
```

A User can have many chips but a Chip can have only one user.

I would like to be able to set the User of a Chip as :

```
chipInstance.setUser(userInstance);
```

as well as :

```
userInstance.addChip(chipInstance);
```

I tried :

```
Chip.belongsTo(User);
User.hasMany(Chip);
```

but when i create an instance of each and try `chipInstance.setUser(userInstance)` and then display the `userInstance`, the `chips` field is an empty array.
How/is this possible, to achieve what I want to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify the table used by both elements with the `through` keyword?

```
Chip.belongsTo(User, {through: 'UserChip'});
User.hasMany(Chip, {through: 'UserChip'});
```

What you try to achieve sounds like this example in the official documentation: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations